# Question about trigonometric equation solution

Tags: trigonometry

Could someone please tell me if this type of trigonometric substitution and solution is correct to make?

$\cos(\alpha )=-cos(\gamma )cos(\lambda )-sin(\gamma )sin(\lambda )\\ cos(\alpha )=-cos(\gamma )cos(\lambda )-cos(90-\gamma )cos(90-\lambda )\\ \alpha =\arccos { [-cos(\gamma )cos(\lambda )-cos(90-\gamma )cos(90-\lambda )] } \\ \alpha =-(\gamma )(\lambda )-(90-\gamma )(90-\lambda )$

Thank you

Comment: No this is not correct: $$\arccos(\cos(x)+\cos(y))\ne x+y$$

Answer (score 0):

> $\alpha =\arccos { [-cos(\gamma )cos(\lambda )-cos(90-\gamma )cos(90-\lambda )] } \\ \alpha =-(\gamma )(\lambda )-(90-\gamma )(90-\lambda )$

Remember that cosine is a function, and not a multiplication, so you cannot just cancel out the inverse cosine with the cosine over here.

Answer (score 0):

Hint for how to solve it:

$$\cos(x\pm y)=\cos x\cos y\mp \sin x \sin y$$

Can you see how to apply that here?